# Sum for a dynamical column Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I have a Kendo Grid. The columns in that grid are dynamically created.
Dynamic columns means the grid will have columns which is defined by a variable.
if variable is set to 5 then 5 columns. if the variable set to 20 then 20 columns gets created.

One of the column I had to sum total and display at the footer of that particular column.
I was able to achieve this functionality using hard coded columns, means I already defined columns in the design time.

But in case of dynamic columns the  footerTemplate: "Total Sum: #=sum#" is not working. it says sum is undefined.

My whole challenge is with footerTemplate: "Total Sum: #=sum#" not working.

Can some one help me with an example?

Regards,
Venu